# How to set service/delay time based on different source and parameter

Tags: anylogic

I am modeling a scenario where say my source is incoming orders, but order may have different characteristics, such as lines, units # of SKUs on the orders. Based on different characteristics, my service/delay time my differ. For example, my service time may be 1s*lines+ 5s*units+30s*SKUs. How can I set up my source and delay block to model this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Create an agent type for orders, add parameters for #SKUs etc.

In your delay block's duration field, use `agent.numSKU` to refer to a parameter `numSKU` in your agent type `Order`.

In your source, make sure it creates `Order` agents (not the default agents).

Lots of example models do this, please follow some of the basic tutorials and check the example models :)